# Installing ActiveMQ using Cygwin

Tags: maven, cygwin, activemq-classic

I have downloaded **ActiveMQ 5.5.0** and followed the instructions  on this page  http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-StartingActiveMQ to install ActiveMQ. I use Cygwin on Windows but when I put **mvn clean install** in the unzipped directory of activeMQ, I got this error :

**BUILD ERROR
Cannot execute mojo: clean. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.**

is there something I didn't catch in the instructions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

You downloaded the binary distribution and not the source.  If so, you do not need to build it using maven.  You can start using it as documented in [Windows Binary Installation](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-WindowsBinaryInstallation)

If it is indeed source distribution, when you unzipped it, it would have created a folder `activemq-parent-5.5.0-source-release` and inside it another folder `activemq-parent-5.5.0`. You would need to go into `activemq-parent-5.5.0` and then run `mvn clean install`.